# My ajax post doesn't seems to do anything

Tags: ajax

I have an ajax post below. It works (the server is reached the success is triggered) but the begin, and the complete don't seems to do something and the update div is not replaced. In fact, except that the server is reached, nothing seems to happen...

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Post",
                        url: myURL,
                        begin: "fctBegin",
                        complete: "fctComplete",
                        mode: "replace",
                        update: "#main-content",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function () { alert('success'); }
                    });
```

Does someone can help me to understand what happened? I'm not very skilled with ajax.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Below is the console trace I get:

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: title of thread suggests...start using a browser console to look for errors and look at ajax requests

Comment: @Tomasz, elrado: I updated my question to show you my console trace

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) there is no such callback as `begin`, there is `beforeSend`.

Answer (score 0):

Function names should not be strings:

```
begin: fctBegin,
complete: fctComplete,
```

Assumming you have functions like:

```
function fctBegin() {//...
function fctComplete() {//...
```

Comment: elrado: I replaced string by functions for begin & complete but still the same problem: nothing seems to happened...

Answer (score 0):

Try using function on complete or begin?